# How can I use goto function across different functions , for outside main ( )

Tags: c, function, goto

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Check (short);

int main()
{
    short a;`

    //[... code ...]

    List :

    //[... code ...]

    Check (a);

    //[... code ...]
}

void Check (short a);
{
    if (a == 1)
    {
        goto List;
    }
}
```

How to implement such usage ?

### ex main

- I want to go to list

  ### - function jump to main
- yas
- i am a beginner

---

1. Please answer me

Comment: 1) you can't. 2) Don't even think about it! 3) Spaghetti belong on a plate with sauce, not in program code! 4) You might want to start an Apple ][ or VIC64 emulator and program them in BASIC. Thoses dialects from the 70ies indeed needed `goto`.

Comment: alternative to "goto"

Comment: Learn the language and how to program. There are book for it ...

Comment: @blackhole: [setjmp and longjmp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setjmp.3.html) allow you to perform non-local gotos, but they are a *pain* in the ass to use correctly.  You really, really, *really* **do not** want to do this.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible in C.

C standard says,

> The identifier in a goto statement shall name a label located
>   somewhere in the enclosing function. A goto statement shall not jump
>   from outside the scope of an identifier having a variably modified
>   type to inside the scope of that identifier.

Comment: alternative to "goto"